# Problems with installing ipopt with conda for pyomo optimization

Tags: python, pyomo, ipopt

For solving nonlinear systems of equations with pyomo I want to use the solver ipopt. On various websites or other questions ([installing Ipopt for anaconda python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30018848/installing-ipopt-for-anaconda-python?rq=4), [Install IPOPT solver to use with pyomo in windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59951763/install-ipopt-solver-to-use-with-pyomo-in-windows)) I have read that it should work relatively easy with conda-forge on Windows (`conda install -c conda-forge ipopt`). However, I always get the message that solving environment is unsuccessful.
Could this be me or is ipopt not available through conda-forge? What would I have to do differently or what other ways are there to easily install ipopt?

I have already tried it via `conda install ipopt`, `conda install -c conda-forge ipopt` or `conda install -c conda-forge/label/cf201901 ipopt`, but in all cases I get the same problems already mentioned.
I've also seen on other sites that you can probably download the solver, unzip (compile?) it and move it to the right place. I just thought that I would like to do it via conda-forge, when it is already described so many times that it should probably go, since this would be the easiest way.

Im needing the solver in a form so that I can use it in a Python script and not, for example, in Google Colab (if that should make a difference).